# Fully Customize UIPIckerView?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiscrollview, scroll, uianimation

[image]

**Target:** To give feel like casino scrollers.

**Description:** I want to make a scroller which will start automatically as i click any button... which scroll with maximum speed and slow down speed and stop after certain speed just like you must have seen in Casino scrolls.

- I am not allowed to use UIPickerView

Can any one please guide me so that i can complete this task

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know this is the heck solution.

If you want to scroll on button clickable (then you would be knowing which position to stop) so you can always use

selectRow:inComponent:animated:
Selects a row in a specified component of the picker view. so you can animate that scroll by selecting row on unwanted position and after some time(you can use timer once the timer is done) select the row at **wanted** position.

Comment: I dont want to use UIPickerView.. is there any alternate way ? like using UIView animations ? Please guide me

Comment: Sorry, i don't know about other controller which can behave like as you are asking but UIPicker view would have been the great idea.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `UIScrollView` with a very large content size and a repeating pattern inside it. You'd probably need extra code to make it only come to a stop at appropriate points. To avoid ever hitting the end of the scroll view, you could jump back up by the length of the repeating pattern whenever you get a chance.